# break a 32bit integer, and use the second half 16bit to form an int

Tags: ios, objective-c, bit-manipulation

I am making an app that downloads a 32bit integer from server, and use the first 16bit and second 16bit for different purposes...

I am responsible for the second 16bit, which should be used to form an int, I know I should use bitwise operation to do this, but unable to achieve, below is the code that I am using, please give me more information.

```
        //CID is a 32bit integer, in nslog it shows as 68913219 - its different for every user
        Byte lowByte = (CID>>16)&0xFF; //the 3rd byte
        Byte highByte = (CID>>24)&0xFF; //the 4th byte
        uint16_t value = lowByte & highByte; //combine, but the result is 0.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
uint16_t value = lowByte & highByte; //combine, but the result is 0.
```

This is not how you combine two bytes into a single `uint16_t`: you are `AND`ing them in place, while you need to shift the high byte, and `OR` it with the low byte:

```
uint16_t value = lowByte | (((uint16_t)highByte) << 8);
```

However, this is suboptimal in terms of readability: if you start with a 32-bit integer, and you need to cut out the upper 16 bits, you could simply shift by 16, and mask with `0xFFFF` - i.e. the same way that you cut out the third byte, but with a 16-bit mask.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do this byte-by-byte. Try this:

```
   //CID is a 32bit integer, in nslog it shows as 68913219 - its different for every user
    uint16_t value = (CID>>16)&0xffff;
```

Comment: eh... don't mind if I sound stupid, but wouldn't that get rip of the 4th byte and return an incorrect result?

Comment: @Craig no - you've shifted the top sixteen bits into the bottom and masked off the top. I'm not sure you even need to mask it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use NSData.

If you have this integer:

`int i = 1;`

You can use :

`NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes: &i length: sizeof(i)];`

and then, to get the second 16bit do:

`int16_t recover;
[data getBytes: &recover range: NSMakeRange(2, 2)]`

Then you have your 16 bits on "recover".

Maybe this way is not so efficient like bit operation, but it is clearer.

:D